# reference error for onclick function in google chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

```
<button onclick = "userClicks()"
                type = "button">Click here!</button>
```

I have the following code running from the button above in an onclick attribute.

```
function userClicks(){ //user clicked, simple increment
clickNumber++;
resetDisplay();
} // userClicks ends
```

It works fine in komodo edit when i preview, and was working on google chrome but now, for a reason i don't know i get a reference error saying the function im calling, userClicks(), is not defined. it is defined in global scope in my javascript file, referenced below.

```
<script type = "text/javascript"
        src = "incremental.js">
```

Can someone help fix this problem or tell me why it's happening???

Comment: You likely have some syntax error somewhere *above* the `userClicks()` function which prevents it being parsed (and hence it's not "defined" on the `window` object).

Comment: Eeek, spaces before and after the `=`

Comment: it's near the top of my js file so i checked all syntax above it, can't find an error and the spaces were inserted while i debugged so i could check for errors clearly

Answer (score 0):

The javascript reference error comes due to one of the following reasons:

1. If file reference of the javascript file containing the function you are using on page is not provided to page.
2. If the path of the js file is not appropriate.
3. If the function doesn't exist in js file.

Check the above criteria and try. Hope this helps.

Comment: in what case would the file reference not be provided to the page? i have a feeling, as ive used chrome's debugger, that for some reason the javascript file is not being loaded at all